# Can't get my page to be responsive for mobile

Tags: html, css

I have watched tutorials and checked on this site but no matter what I do I 
   can't get my page to be  responsive for mobile. I want the image on top and 
   the text in a nice paragraph below. I am new to html and css, I don't know 
   any others. The code I'm adding is the original before I tried to make it 
   responsive.

```
   <DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Home</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="merchandise.css"
   </head>



    <div class="header">
    <img class="banner-image" src="ccc.png" width="100%" height="150px">




    </div>

    <ul class="nav">



    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>   
    <li><a href="menu.php">Menu</a></li> 
    <li><a href="entertowin.php">Enter to Win</a></li> 
    <li><a href="merchandise.php">Merchandise</a></li> 
    <li><a href="events.php">Events</a></li> 
    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>

    </ul>  







     <style>

    .float-img {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 10px;
     margin-left: 5px;    
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     padding: 2px;
     border: none;
     border-color: #ffb6c1ff;

     }



      </style>



   <body>

    <img src="british-shorthair-3055340_1920.jpg" width:"400" height="400" 

   class="float-img">

    <style>

    p {margin-left: 250px; margin-top: 40px;
     margin-right: 20px;
     line-height: 38px;
    } 

    </style>

   <font size="5" color="#00b8e6" font-align: center > 


   <p>



  Step into a magical world of cats at Cat Corner Cafe. Enjoy eating cute 
   cat themed foods and drinks in a relaxing environment. Spend some quality 
  time 
playing with some feline friends. Enjoy watching the cats have fun in an 
environment made just for them. All cats will be adoptable and provided by 
the local shelter. Cat Corner Cafe will also have fun events like cat yoga, 
art with cats and game days. Come by yourself, with your meetup group or 
have your next birthday party here! We look forward to seeing you. To be 
alerted when we open please sign up with your email on our homepage.


   </p>
    </text>
  </body>


   </head>
   </html>


    body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  font-family: 'arial', serif;
   }

  .nav {
  background-color:#ffb6c1;
  color:#ffffff
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 20px 0 20px 0;

 }

  .nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;

  }

   .nav> li > a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #ffffff
   }

   .nav > li > a:hover {
   color:   #C0C0C0
   }

   .banner {
   width: 100;
   display: block;


   }

   .banner > .bannerimage {
   width: 100;
   height: 100;
   display: block;


   }

  ul.nav{
  margin: 0;
  }

 div.left {
 width: 50%; 
 padding: 0 0 0 5%;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 float: left}


 div.right {
 width: 50%; 
 padding: 0 5% 0 0;
 float: right}
 p {
 padding-top: 25px;
 text-align: left;
  }
```

Comment: By the way, your `<link>` tag is not closed in the example you've provided. That could prove problematic later on.

Comment: It might be just a cut-n-paste issue, but you have an error in your markup. Your stylesheet link tag is not closed and thus might not load. It's a little cleaner to use css backgrounds, rather than loading background images (like your banner) in an image tag. You also need to learn about tag placement. You have content that is outside the body tag and your browser has to determine the best way to handle that (usually it gets it wrong).

Comment: If you want people to be able to help you, you need to provide more information. In what way, exactly, do you want your page to be responsive?  What did you try? What went wrong?

Also, please trim down your code to a minimal example which can answer your question. Putting up a huge block like this is intimidating and makes it harder for people to find where the problem is.

Comment: The website on a desktop looks fine. When I look at the webpage on my phone the header is the right size and the nav bar but the image is too wide and the text is one long skinny paragraph. I've tried so many things. I tried code I found on this website and watched some tutorials. I just want the image to be right below the navbar and below the image to be the paragraph so when someone is on a cellphone they can read it easily.

Answer (score 4):

**Fixing your HTML first!**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="merchandise.css">    

  <style>

    .float-img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;    
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: none;
    border-color: #ffb6c1ff;
    }

    p {
    margin-left: 250px; 
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height: 38px;
    } 


    @media (max-width: 1024px) {

    body img {
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    }

    body div img {
    max-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    }
    
    }


  </style>

</head>  
<body>
    <div class="header">
      <img class="banner-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Mauritius_Road_Signs_-_Warning_Sign_-_Road_works.svg/1160px-Mauritius_Road_Signs_-_Warning_Sign_-_Road_works.svg.png" width="1365px" height="150px">
    </div>

    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>   
      <li><a href="menu.php">Menu</a></li> 
      <li><a href="entertowin.php">Enter to Win</a></li> 
      <li><a href="merchandise.php">Merchandise</a></li> 
      <li><a href="events.php">Events</a></li> 
      <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>  

    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Mauritius_Road_Signs_-_Warning_Sign_-_Road_works.svg/1160px-Mauritius_Road_Signs_-_Warning_Sign_-_Road_works.svg.png" width:"400" height="400"> 

   <div class="float-img">
     <p>Step into a magical world of cats at Cat Corner Cafe. Enjoy eating cute 
cat themed foods and drinks in a relaxing environment. Spend some quality 
time playing with some feline friends. Enjoy watching the cats have fun in an 
environment made just for them. All cats will be adoptable and provided by 
the local shelter. Cat Corner Cafe will also have fun events like cat yoga, 
art with cats and game days. Come by yourself, with your meetup group or 
have your next birthday party here! We look forward to seeing you. To be 
alerted when we open please sign up with your email on our homepage.</p>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now for the right solution without framework use `@media` Queries. Do your homework [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp) .

Now for you the easy **Solution** to get this responsive is looking into using an HTML framework ,such as the famous [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/), which you wil have to learn allot to fully understand the power behind it but Bootstrap has good documentation to get you going.

Comment: I tried using @media queries but the image was still too big. What would the exact code look like? I know I'm doing something wrong, I just have no idea what.

Comment: updated the code added a media query and you can see it works. hope it helps you.

Comment: I just want to mention in your `HTML` within the `body` tag your image(`<img widht="400" height="400">`) tags have fixed widths and heights so if you view the snippet full page you should see that original size, as full page on desktop does not meet the media queries range.

Answer (score 3):

You're gonna have to fix your code (html stuff) first and then learn to use media queries.

With media queries, you can target different devices and write specific css that applies to only those devices.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

**DO NOT LEARN A FRAMEWORK JUST YET**

You should build your knowledge of HTML and CSS first and have  a firm understanding of both of them before learning any framework. This will insure that when you learn any framework, you'll be able to **make the framework work the way you want**.. If you start relying on a framework just yet, **you will work according to the framework**

Comment: I wholly second this. You should really understand the fundamentals before messing with frameworks.

Comment: I've tried media queries. No matter what I do the image won't fit.

Comment: you html is the problem have a lok at my awnser

Comment: Fix you html first. There are a lot of errors. Something like https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html or some other online tool should help.

Comment: I'm using the site to fix my code, thanks. What would you suggest for making my paragraph and photo responsive?

Comment: Take a look at the media query link I posted. Youtube and learn the basics of how media queries work.. When you have an understanding, probably all you need to do is use media query to target small screen devices and then remove the floats from image and/or paragraph and set their width to 100%... or something like that.

Comment: I checked out the website and I only have three errors left, yey. lol One of the errors is Bad value “100%” for attribute “width” on element “img”: Expected a digit but saw “%” instead. Another one is Bad value “150px” for attribute “height” on element “img”: Expected a digit but saw “p” instead. I had the image as 100% so the banner would be responsive. It does show up perfectly on my cellphone. How do I fix the code?

Comment: Remove those inline properties and give the image a class and style it in CSS the way you want. Html should primarily just have the content of the site.. CSS is for styling.

Comment: Okay, so I tried checking out another page of mine on the website and it said I had 5 mistakes. I fixed one and then it said I have 34! What the heck?! How does that happen? All I did was add a ! to the doctype tag.

Comment: You probably did a typo somewhere.. recheck everything.. I've had it happen many times when I was a beginner that I thought that there were no mistakes and after a couple hours I found a typo.. so check for that.

Comment: After putting my code through the website and removing all errors and css elements I'm trying to make it work. I removed all of the styling elements and put them in the css file but it just isn't looking right. Can you message me? It won't let me message you bc I haven't been on the site long enough. Should it be okay to have some css elements in my html page? I did remove all of the errors. I want to have the code as it should be but it's just looking really strange now that I moved all of the styling elements to only the css page.

Comment: Have no css elements on your page.. I think you should learn the basics further. I can't msg you I don't see any option to.

Comment: I definitely need to learn more and am watching videos, reading and trying. I really need to get this website up and fixed as soon as possible. Can I email you my fixed code? I've been sick this week and I'm new to code, not a good combo.

Comment: Actually, I can post my code as a new question. I'm trying to fix the about me page. http://www.catcornercafe.com/aboutus.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551615/moved-all-styling-elements-to-css-page-now-my-page-doesnt-look-right You can find my new code here.

Comment: Looks like somebody just solved it for you on that question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Like a previous answer

> You're gonna have to fix your code (html stuff) first

But, if for now you don't want to invest a lot of time learning about media queries or code a few rules in CSS, I'd suggest you use a framework and skip the design part, while still making your page look minimally presentable with a tidy look.

I recommend you give a look at [Tacit](https://yegor256.github.io/tacit/) CSS framework. It's ideal for people with zero CSS and design skills and it doesn't involve creating CSS rules from the ground up, you just worry about your HTML code and you need to include [Tacit](https://yegor256.github.io/tacit/)'s CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS framework. I will recommend bootstrap CSS framework. It will handle all of that for you. UIkit and Foundation are good alternatives too.

Answer (score 0):

In order for an image to be considered as a solid object in css it must have the "display: block;" attribute. You might need to also set the same style property to the text paragraph.

Try the following:

```
.float-img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 5px;    
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding: 2px;
 border: none;
 border-color: #ffb6c1ff;
 display: block;
}
```

Explanation:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ it is html/css framework for making responsive websites. Check out how to make a grid layout.

You can dig into media queries yourself but that is not exactly needed if you use a framework https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries